# Cannot link TopHat against libboost_thread.a

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

I am trying to analyze data generated from RNA-seq experiments. I am trying to align the RNA-Seq reads to the genome using TopHat. But, I have got struck while installing the TopHat!

To begin with I have downloaded the following packages:

- tophat-2.1.0.tar.gz
- samtools-0.1.19.tar.bz2
- boost_1_54_0.zip

I have unpacked all the packages.

**For samtools:**
I have copied all C-header files in samtools-0.1.19/install/include/bam
Then I copied the libbam.a file in samtools-0.1.19/install/lib

**For boost:**
I have used the following commands

```
$./bootstrap.sh
$./b2 install --prefix=PREFIX
```

**For TopHat:**
I have used the command line:

```
$./configure \
  --prefix=/path/to/tophat-2.1.0 \
  --with-boost=/path/to/boost_1_54_0/PREFIX \
  --with-bam=/path/to/samtools-0.1.19/install
```

But I am getting an error message. The last few lines of the error are as follows:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.38.0... yes
checking for bamlib... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... no
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... (cached) no
checking for exit in -llibboost_thread.a... no
configure: error: Could not link against libboost_thread.a !
```

Now my question is why I am getting the error message and what can be done to overcome this. I have tried the same in both x86_64 Ubuntu systems, but got the same error all the time!

Comment: Possibly you did not create the static libraries for boost: https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.tutorial.linkage also, if you are not bound to a specific boost version try to install boost from your system repositry, for example on debian derived linuxes: `sudo apt install libboost-thread-dev`